# WPF - two way binding but different sources

Tags: wpf, binding

Is it possible to binding to control from 2 different sources? I've got situation like this: I open the window of adding new product. I'd like to binding items to comboboxes from my enums (all possible values), but I'd like to bind selected enum value to my product object too. Is it possible to set difference sources depends on the way of binding? How can I do that?

Comment: your situation has two different properties: ItemSource and SelectedValue/SelectedItem.

Comment: Can you be title clear, do you want to bind from 2 diff source means 2 diff class, or you want to bind to diff properties for 1 for Enum values and 1 for selected value. If you want to bind 2 properties use ItemSource and SelectedValue/SelectedItem/SelectedIndex as mentioned by lomed

Comment: This sort of thing happens a lot.  Consider using an intermediator property.

Comment: @Kumareshan - i don't want to use SelectedItem or SelectedValue etc. because I don't want to write code behind. I want to do everything in xaml. So i need to set one source for way from source to view (values of enum) and other source to binding to source from view (property of my product object).

Comment: I'm not able to understand your requirement could please explain in it with an example

Comment: I have window of adding new product and for example I have a combobox "Product type". In my application i have enum ProductType with values Mouse, Keyboard, Headphones etc. So values of this enum should be shown in combobox - no problem. But when user select value in combobox i want to automatically bind it to the property of product object. So there is a problem - binding to view from one source and binding from view to the other source. I want to do this only in xaml to properly use MVVM pattern. I don't want to write any code behind and use SelectedItem property.